# Get notified when static property changes in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) microsoft described that in wpf 4.5 we can use INotifypropertyChanged for static properties as well. So I tried to do that.

Here is the code:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
    protected static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
```

But I dont know what to use instead of `this` keyword in the above code?

Here is my code:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
protected static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}

private static Haemogram _cHaemogram;
public static Haemogram cHaemogram
{
    get
    {
        return _cHaemogram;
    }
    set
    {
        _cHaemogram = value;
        OnStaticPropertyChanged("cHaemogram");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that you added this to your viewmodel :

```
  yourClass.StaticPropertyChanged+= yourClassStaticPropertyChanged;
```

...

```
  void yourClassStaticPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

The "this" keyword refers the "object sender" parameter. 
If you use "this" in your code while creating handler, it refers "sender" in yourClassStaticPropertyChanged function. If you send null, the sender parameter will be null.

--Edit--

If you want to get changes to the textbox add this code to your viewmodel :

```
private string _updatedText;
public string UpdatedText
{
  get
  {
      return _updatedText;
  }
  set
  {
      _updatedText= value;
      OnStaticPropertyChanged("UpdatedText")
  }
}
```

And set UpdatedText in the event :

```
void yourClassStaticPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                UpdatedText=e.NewValue;
        }
```

then bind the UpdatedText to your textbox like this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdatedText}"/>
```

Comment: No, I have not added the code that you mentioned. If I want to add the above code then 

(1) where should the first line of your code I declare?

(2) What should I write between the curly braces in above code?

Comment: what is your aim? what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I have used your code in the constructor of the MainWindowViewModel. Now the event is being raised. But Changes are not returned to the TextBox. Anyway if you can help then I have uploaded a demo project stating my problem. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2XAE1EBI6rTVRkSUNBUWpNbFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you join the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43329/discussion-between-khushi-and-sampath

Comment: Thank you. I have not tried your code as I have moved my code of all viewmodels in one viewmodel.

Answer (score 7):

Unless anything *uses* the sender parameter, it won't matter. Logically it would make sense to use the type:

```
handler(typeof(TypeDeclaringEvent), new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
```

EDIT: Note that in the document you referred to, it states:

> The static event can use either of the following signatures.
>
> ```
>    public static event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;
>    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
> ```

Your event doesn't comply with these, which could be an issue.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by `TypeDeclaringEvent`

Comment: He means the name of the class that this is declared in.

Comment: @Khushi: Whatever type is declaring the event - you haven't shown it in your sample code, so I couldn't guess a type name.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tried to follow your answer and my code is updated in question. But still I am not getting notified when static property changes.

Comment: @Khushi: What do you mean by "I am not getting notified"? What isn't? Have you subscribed to the event? Are you actually raising the event?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what event you are talking about?

Comment: @Khushi: The event that you've declared in your code! `public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I am raising that event in `OnStaticPropertyChanged(string Propertyname)` see the `handler`.

Comment: @Khushi: Yes, but I mean in your debugging, are you checking that it's actually being raised - that you're getting to that code? And that anything has actually subscribed to the event? Currently you've given us very little information...

Comment: @JonSkeet Just now I have checked it and the event is not being raised. `Handler` is always `null`.

Comment: @Khushi: Right, so that means nothing is subscribing to the event. So that's the next thing to investigate. (You haven't given enough context to know why you'd *expect* anything to subscribe to the event...)

Comment: @Khushi: See my edit for one possible problem - your event type doesn't comply with the signatures suggested by MSDN.

Comment: @JonSkeet Should I upload my project?

Comment: @Khushi: No, but creating a short but complete example (not your real project - *just* enough to be a complete program demonstrating the problem) would be useful... if my edit doesn't help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have edited my code as msdn and your answer suggested but still event does not raise. And for your above comment I could not create a new project for you because I cannot demonstrate the problem from other project.

Comment: @Khushi: Well if it all works fine in a short but complete other project, then I'm not going to be able to help you - you need to look *very carefully* at the differences between a project in which it works and a project in which it doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK then I will try to create a new project for you but it will take some time as I am a newbie. Is that fine?

Comment: @Khushi: Yes, although given that I've answered the question of how to raise the event, you might wish to create a separate question for the subscription part... if that even ends up being a problem. (You may well work out what's wrong while creating the new project.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have uploaded a sample project with the same behaviour https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bYjgzUlR1b21PNDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Khushi: That's *far* more than is required to demonstrate this. You don't need multiple pages and you *certainly* don't need anything to do with the entity framework.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you are right. But I have tried to create the mini-copy of my project.

Comment: @Khushi: But that's not what I suggested. No-one else wants to wade through lots of code. I'm suggesting you start again and create a project which does *nothing* but demonstrate this problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I don't use multiple pages then I don't need a static property. I have used static property here because my project is divided into different pages. And I have used entity framework in the Sample project for finding the errors that I might have done in binding if any.

Comment: @Khushi: You've misunderstood the point of creating the smaller project. It doesn't matter that you wouldn't *need* a static property on just one page (although I'd say that's a design flaw anyway - you shouldn't use a static property for that IMO) - it matters that you try to demonstrate the problem as simply as possible. I'm afraid I don't have time to continue this discussion further.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok. Thank you for your help. As you wish.