# Where i need to define INotifyPropertyChanged in case of Base and sub classes

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

i have this `Base class`:

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile
{
    protected string _fileName;
    protected int _packets;
    protected int _packetsSent;
    protected string _duration;

    public int Packets
    {
        get { return _packets; }
        set { _packets = value; }
    }

    public int PacketsSent
    {
        get { return _packetsSent; }
        set { _packetsSent = value; }
    }
}
```

And this sub class:

```
public class Libpcap : WiresharkFile, IDisposable, IEnumerable<WiresharkFilePacket>
{
    ....
}
```

Create my object:

```
WiresharkFile wiresahrkFile = new Libpcap(file);
```

My collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile> wiresharkFiles { get; set; }
```

Send packets:

```
wiresahrkFile.Sendpackets();
```

At this point all my `wiresahrkFile` (`Libpcap` type) properties is changing so i wonder where i need to define this `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: does the UI need to be aware of this changes?

Comment: Yes, i want to update my UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your xaml is binded to properties of WiresharkFile then a WiresharkFile have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, if not it will lead to the memory leaks ([Top 3 Memory Leak Inducing Pitfalls of WPF Programming](http://magicaldebugging.com/top-3-memory-leak-inducing-pitfalls-of-wpf-programming/)). If your binding is defined only on a Libpcap class then the Libpcap have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. In my projects I create a base implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface ,and then each base models and base view models just inherits from that implementation. Here some base code:
 1. Base implementation:

```
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

2. Your model (in my opinion):

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _fileName;
    private int _packets;
    private int _packetsSent;
    private string _duration;

    public int Packets
    {
        get { return _packets; }
        set
        {
            _packets = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int PacketsSent
    {
        get { return _packetsSent; }
        set
        {
            _packetsSent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

regards,

Comment: Why you created this BaseObservableObject, why not using INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: Because it allows you to use `OnPropertyChanged();` in the derived class without needing to include the code for it. It is the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) coding principal. You are likely to have dozens of classes that all need `INotifyPropertyChanged`, instead of writing the same `OnPropertyChagned()` in every single class you only need to write it once and then do `:BaseObservableObject` on your 12 classes.

Comment: So just derive from BaseObservableObject inside my Base class (WiresharkFile) and add OnPropertyChanged() for each property that changed ? (no need to do it this way: OnPropertyChanged("Propert name")) ?

Comment: BTW i have also static property: is it possible to add OnPropertyChanged for static property ?

Comment: @davidhol about the  first question "So just..."; yes in case of using the 4.5 .Net, if you are using a 4.0 dot.net version you will still have to do it an old way (OnPropertyChanged("Propert name")) or OnPropertyChanged(()=>Propert name)). About the last question here are a couple of links that explains the way how to bind to static; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612066/get-notified-when-static-property-changes-in-wpf  and http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties but please remember about the memory leaks issues.

Comment: @davidhol feel free to mark it as answered if you feel that my answer was helpful for you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer with  IIan but for C# 8 and .Net Framework 4.8.

*1. Base Model*

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
        {
            string propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser?.Body).Member.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged(propName);
        }

        protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(name);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

*2. Your Model*

```
public class Current : ObservableObject
{
        private string _status;

        public Current()
        {
            Status = "Not Connected";
        }

        public string Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                _status = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); // call this to update
            }
        }
}
```

*3. How to use?*

```
<Label Content="{Binding Status}"/>
```